# has_one association through has_many with dynamic conditions - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have three tables:

```
class Keeper
  has_many :assignments
end

class Assignment
  belongs_to :keeper
  belongs_to :assignment_group
end

class AssignmentsGroup
  has_many :assignments
  validate :uniqueness_of_keeper
end
```

Assignments associated with a single assignment_group must have a single keeper. My question is: how can I add a `has_one: keeper` association to `AssignmentsGroup` given that all associated assignments will have the same keeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I've misunderstood your problem as it's not clear what the association to between `AssignmentGroup` and `Assignment` should be, but try this:

```
class Keeper
  has_many :assignments
end

class Assignment
  belongs_to :keeper
  belongs_to :assignment_group # will need to add a reference to the assignments table
end

class AssignmentsGroup
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :keepers, through: assignments
  validate :single_keeper

  private     

  def single_keeper
    errors.add(:base, "can only have one keeper") unless keepers.uniq.length == 1
  end
end
```

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: whoops, forgot to add the `belongs_to`. Yes, `Assignment belongs_to :assignment_group`. My question is how can I add `has_one :keeper` to `AssignmentGroup`

Comment: @dn1985 you can't cause there are many keepers if `AssignmentsGroup` `has_many :assignments`. But with a validation rule you should be able to add that constraint, which is what I tried to show above in `single_keeper` validation.